# np.size and np.mean missing values in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science, mean

I have a data set with movie ratings and i'm trying to get the mean rating of each movie and number of ratings for each movie. I use pandas agg function to aggregate the ratings column and calculate np.size and np.mean
However it keeps returning NaN values for some movies even though they have at least 1 rating. I will drop all movies which have only one rating but since np.size returns some NaN values I don't know which ones to drop

[Image of the ratings dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FEx0.png)

[Image of the missing values after running the code below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSYmQ.png)

```
movieProperties = ratings_df.groupby('movieId').agg({'rating': [np.size, np.mean]})
```

Comment: First, use `'mean'` and `'size'` ... `ratings_df.groupby('movieId').agg({'rating': ['count', 'mean']})`.  I used `'count'` instead because it counts non-nan values.

Comment: Second, Numpy needs to be told to skip nans. `ratings_df.groupby('movieId').agg({'rating': [np.size, np.nanmean]})`

Comment: Any particular reason for using numpy here? It doesn't make much sense to me when pandas already includes this functionality. Also, when do you intend to drop the movies with only 1 rating?

Comment: @Alexander Cécile, nope no particular reason to use numpy. I was unaware that pandas could also do the trick. I want to drop movies right after I find the count value of which ones have just one rating

Comment: Have the comments by @piRSquared been enough to get you sorted?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I tried using `ratings_df.groupby('movieId').agg({'rating': ['count', 'mean']})` but the issue still remains. There are still missing values and even some with missing number of ratings but they have an average rating.

Comment: I tried replicating the issue, but no luck. No missing data, calculations seem fine. Can you share the full dataset? The error might be coming from there.